# Getting "'Emulation.setCPUThrottlingRate' wasn't found" error on Mac and Windows os when trying to set this in the Protocol Monitor tab in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, cpu, devtools, throttling

I'm trying to simulate CPU throtling by puttin this command:

```
{"command":"Emulation.setCPUThrottlingRate","parameters":{"rate": 20}}
```

In the chrome dev tools protocol monitor tab.
Tried either on Mac and Windows os.
Getting this error:

```
{
    "code": -32601,
    "message": "'Emulation.setCPUThrottlingRate' wasn't found"
}
```

Chrome version:

```
Version 122.0.6261.112 (Official Build) (arm64)
```

Any suggestions how to fix this would be appreciable. Thank you.